# What are the definitions of "P-path" and "MM-path" in the integration testing?

Tags: integration-testing

I have a problem with laboratory work in university: what are the definitions of "P-path" and "MM-path" in the integration testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method/Message Path:**

An MM-Path in object-oriented software is a sequence of method executions linked by messages.

**Atomic System Function (ASF)**

An atomic system function (ASF) is an MM-path that begins with an input port event and ends with an output port event

[image]

Answer (score 0):

P-path is `Procedure-path`, means direct call of public method.
MM-path is `Method-message path`, means all method, which were called.

I didn't find sources in literature, but our lecturer said, that these definitions are from `specificity in integration testing of object-oriented software` theme.